# Downloading PDF's in Ruby with open uri and IO copy

Tags: ruby, pdf, download, uri

I am trying to download a PDF from a URL that is provided after an API call to a shipping company.

They provide a URL that looks something like this:
https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=l9I62LZP%2bn8M%2boI3%2fEf2IEPUFgbVSCGGM5vsMfEChmwP%2b4Rbdzo%2bQ5mJ58mGLo%2fBsAezuXgbZ2LZ2y%2bmXIkxDPs8tXjOMyhFcwgN3NxVvGrUrw%2fT6G0vHK1bjZBt5SBN2BXHxSd0orFkX6EzNk%2f8ZQXicxoVpzNDyLhQJNms8gY%3d

The problem is using `open('https://url.com/etcetc*#*')` is put in plain text wrapped in quotations, it works.

But when I use a variable, because these URLs will obviously change. It stops working and I get errors such as:

> ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:359:in 'open_http': 404 Not Found (OpenURI::HTTPError)

It seems the formatting of the URL is changing in some way between plain text and putting that plain text in a variable?

```rb
  #imageMatch is coming from an API request, it looks like so:
  #imageMatch = '<URL>https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=l9I62LZP%2bn8M%2boI3%2fEf2INAfAaYeiqrVYtqgOSM9lRdBvm41QhPDuE4zLzewx476oW305pVmQB4Dbh1r1gQIwK2AMKsTBjlUB3C4Y%2bAn65AifJlkm404gcLmo1xHxgl3uMt%2f9kxrxcgXkwLgtr4xhK3LL17hFdV0d9VFz4fQamg%3d</URL>'

  imageMatch = imageMatch.to_s
  imageMatch = imageMatch.sub(/<URL>/, '"')
  imageMatch = imageMatch.sub(/<\/URL>/, '"')


  File.open(finalLabel, "wb") do |f|
    #this hardcoded link works, but once we put it in a variable, poof, its broken...
    #download = open('https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=l9I62LZP%2bn8M%2boI3%2fEf2IEPUFgbVSCGGM5vsMfEChmwP%2b4Rbdzo%2bQ5mJ58mGLo%2fBsAezuXgbZ2LZ2y%2bmXIkxDPs8tXjOMyhFcwgN3NxVvGrUrw%2fT6G0vHK1bjZBt5SBN2BXHxSd0orFkX6EzNk%2f8ZQXicxoVpzNDyLhQJNms8gY%3d')

    download = open(imageMatch)

    IO.copy_stream(download, finalLabel)
  end
```

I have tried executing it instead with wget and also parsing it with URI but I can't get a method to work for downloading this PDF.

EDIT:

I have currently tried to isolate this code into its own class that is passed the url and file name. I am still however running into the same issues where a hardcoded url will work. But the variable placed seems to return a 404.

My current code now:

```html
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'fileutils'

def pdf_download label_path, label_name
  
  label64 = IO.read(label_path)
  res_link = label64.match(/<URL>*.*<\/URL>/)

  res_link = res_link.to_s
  res_link = res_link.sub /<URL>/, ''
  res_link = res_link.sub /<\/URL>/, ''

  res_link = res_link.sub /\r/,''
  #res_link = res_link.sub /\n/,''
  link = res_link.strip

  finalLabel = label_name+".pdf"

  #this method works, but same issue, the variable https link causes a 404...
  #exec("wget -O "+label_name+".pdf "+link)

  uri = URI.parse(link)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new URI(uri)
  req.initialize_http_header({'User-Agent' => 'Ruby'})
  result = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') { |http| http.request req}

  puts result.code

  File.open(finalLabel, "wb") do |f|
    f.write(result.body)

    #download = open(link)
    #IO.copy_stream(download, finalLabel)
  end
end
```

So as per some of the suggestions to try and see what is being used through the debugger. This is the output showing the filename, url link and the command itself.

```
D, [2023-08-30T09:50:13.893259 #1298] DEBUG -- : J348920.pdf
```

D, [2023-08-30T09:50:13.893374 #1298] DEBUG -- : https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=LmcDWDH7bdfyBimsSQxinGRHYK6tOMarMK27yTOsnKj4I9Lg5fNH6nunFQ7amhXgw%2fkfQTSHyeskPem7mpwDBNl4KjdBLSjXxY%2bDUbAF5qLXpdrTBgcDMMr2%2bpiywphwNp4aSKG9ZnGTEyYh%2fx63XrewMoinVzeWYyugaSSSiJs%3d
D, [2023-08-30T09:50:13.893471 #1298] DEBUG -- : wget -O J348920.pdf https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=LmcDWDH7bdfyBimsSQxinGRHYK6tOMarMK27yTOsnKj4I9Lg5fNH6nunFQ7amhXgw%2fkfQTSHyeskPem7mpwDBNl4KjdBLSjXxY%2bDUbAF5qLXpdrTBgcDMMr2%2bpiywphwNp4aSKG9ZnGTEyYh%2fx63XrewMoinVzeWYyugaSSSiJs%3d
--2023-08-30 09:50:13--  https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=LmcDWDH7bdfyBimsSQxinGRHYK6tOMarMK27yTOsnKj4I9Lg5fNH6nunFQ7amhXgw%2fkfQTSHyeskPem7mpwDBNl4KjdBLSjXxY%2bDUbAF5qLXpdrTBgcDMMr2%2bpiywphwNp4aSKG9ZnGTEyYh%2fx63XrewMoinVzeWYyugaSSSiJs%3d
Resolving eshiponline.purolator.com (eshiponline.purolator.com)... 198.33.112.12
Connecting to eshiponline.purolator.com (eshiponline.purolator.com)|198.33.112.12|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-08-30 09:50:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters exclusively. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: First, determine if the URL you're generating with text substitution is correct or not before fetching.

Comment: Why are you putting quotes *in* your URL?

Comment: I had put quotes in the URL to attempt getting it to work as the string I receive the URL from doesn't have them. And when I hardcoded the link it only was working in quotes.

Comment: I am printing out the URL after sanitizing it from the API response I save to an xml file. It looks like so with no quotes: https://eshiponline.purolator.com/ShipOnline/shipment/getLabel.ashx?i=LmcDWDH7bdfyBimsSQxinOfN2zz9EYVlB3yZOiW5fNu%2fIBsdaGqPrcox5%2f0lUBFCQVsWzCht74a7FygeAQMyZeF1FujMF131P14Oi0GkdWz%2fDLuq%2fIW0Ux%2b1UNzpMQm4Nna7Ccq7azLKknErXzVDv9RRxGra3YNElPR%2fweJCCgI%3d

Comment: Why are you using ruby 2.3?

It is no longer supported and not receiving any security patches since 2019. https://endoflife.date/ruby

Comment: Also, are you actually using the ruby builtin `open` method here? Because I cannot reproduce your results. Maybe you have some custom implementation of `open`?

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.3 because this is part of a program that is integrated to a few legacy programs we have in house. It unfortunately is not feasible for me to overhaul our system to accommodate newer versions at this time.

Comment: How should I check if I am using a modified version of the open() method? Would I check in the location of the gems? As far as require libraries I use for this. I have 'net/http', 'uri', 'open-uri', 'fileutils' included in my current code.

Comment: Hi K J, you are discovering why I am perplexed by this scenario. All of the avenues I've tried, curl, wget included all work when you place the url in as plain text. But when I parse that url, make sure it's got no newline chars, etc and use it in a variable, the problems start. I get 404 errors instead of the 200 OK. It seems something with reading a new url from the xml response I get back and placing it in a variable is breaking it somehow.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions, it's just rather odd.